# How to detect if an app is running with Cloud9?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud9-ide, mongohq

I'm developping a node application, sometimes with Eclipse (locally) and sometimes with Cloud9 (remotely). As I'm using a database, I have one local with mongoDB and another remote on mongoHQ.

If I dont want to use the DB on mongoHQ when I work locally, how could I tell my nodejs application (understand automatically detect) that my IDE is Cloud9 or another one ? I could use a simple local variable that I change each time I change IDE, but is it possible to do it automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to detect [cloud9-ide](/questions/tagged/cloud9-ide) is to check if `C9_PROJECT` environment variable is set:

```
if (process.env.C9_PROJECT) {
  console.log('Running on C9 IDE');
} else {
  // ...
}
```

There are also other variables prefixed with **C9**. You can check them if you want to.